# How can i unit test a "Delete link" with Ror, cucumber - webrat?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, cucumber, webrat

I am currently developing a Rails application, I'm trying to units test it. I chose Cucumber + WebRater. I'd like to test in my backend all delete link.

I tried to go to visit a second argument (the method: delete) without success.
(something like : visit my_path, method => :delete)

On my pages I delete some links so the solution click_link ("Delete") is not acceptable.

I appeal to your experience in this field.

Thank you in advance

Gaetan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webrat just needs a simple patch to get it to work with rails3's new unobtrusive JavaScript.

See here for explanation and a link to the patch:

https://webrat.lighthouseapp.com/projects/10503/tickets/365-allow-webrat-to-read-the-data-method-attribute

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The method :delete us Javascript to made the good request to you server with a POST and _method='put".

Webrat don't know how interprete the Javascript. If you want that, you need use some backend with it. Capybara or Selenium.

Comment: There is a simple patch to get webrat to work with the rails3 unobtrusive js, see:  https://webrat.lighthouseapp.com/projects/10503/tickets/365-allow-webrat-to-read-the-data-method-attribute